# Running command in a new bash shell process

Tags: bash, ssh

I have looked around as I would've thought this would be a rather common question, but nothing seems to be working for me.

Basically I'm trying to SSH into a device (Raspberry Pi) to run a process.  The process is `node ./bin/www`.  I wrote a `publish.sh` script that does a few things before this, but when I run the command `ssh user@hostname "cd <my-location>;node ./bin/www` it respectively starts the process in my current bash shell.

What I'm looking to do is open up a *new* bash shell to run that command, as that process will start a web server.

I tried wrapping my `ssh` command in `bash -c 'ssh ...'` but it still runs in the same shell window that the `publish.sh` script was kicked off in.  Am I doing something wrong?  What exactly do I need to do in my shell script to run a command in a new bash shell process?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your purpose in running this in a new shell? Are you hoping to log off and leave it running after? If so, you need to do more than just run it in a separate shell, so if so, you should tell us these details. :)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie nope, I just want my current shell to not be "hung up" on running that other process.

Comment: I may be failing to properly imagine what you're doing, but I don't think this will accomplish that either, because the new shell also takes over your terminal until it quits. Are you just wanting to run the server detached from your terminal?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie maybe. So I have a bash terminal open and I'm doing "things". Then I want to SSH into another machine and run a web server (which, will run indefinitely until I kill it). But I want to keep doing "other things" in the shell as well. But if the web server runs in my shell I would have to open up another terminal.  I'd rather just have a command to start the web server in a new shell process. Make sense?

Comment: Makes sense to do, yes! And what you've asked for won't (unless I'm seriously out to lunch at the moment) do the job. You should put that description of your goal into your question and solicit new answers. IIRC (I'm not in reach of a terminal at the moment), starting a new shell process will still prevent you from doing other things in the current terminal because it takes over as the “foreground” process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `ssh` with `-n` option as,

```
ssh -Xn user@hostname <command> <argument>
```

Use of `-X` is optional to forward X11. In your case,

```
ssh -n user@hostname node ./bin/www
```

**Example:** To open a text file (file.txt) in remote machine with `gedit`,

```
ssh -Xn user@hostname gedit file.txt
```

From [`man ssh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ssh.1)

```
-n      A common trick is to use this to run X11 programs on a remote machine.  For example,
         ssh -n shadows.cs.hut.fi emacs & will start an emacs on shadows.cs.hut.fi, and the X11 connection will be
         automatically forwarded over an encrypted channel.  The ssh program will be put in the background.
```

Comment: Also see the `-f` option, in case you want to use password authentication.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be opening a *new* bash shell/process to run that command. It's still running it in the same window when I do this.

Comment: yes it will run in the same window but does create new process.

Comment: @souravc ah ok!  I think that works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To do this using shell:

```
ssh -t master 'bash -ic "{ cd <my-location>; node ./bin/www ;} &"'
```

A bit strict using `disown` (`nohup` can be used too):

```
ssh -t master 'bash -ic "{ cd <my-location>; node ./bin/www ;} & disown"'
```

- `-t` will allocate a pseudo TTY to enable job control
- `bash -i` will make the shell interactive, otherwise the connection to the master will be closed

In your case, you can get away without the command grouping `{}`:

```
ssh -t master 'bash -ic "cd <my-location>; node ./bin/www &"'
```

Comment: (1) Maybe I’m just being picky, but I find `{ …;} &` to be misleading/confusing.  Why not use the more familiar `( … ) &`?  (2) Are you sure you need the `-t`?  You definitely need to have a TTY to do Ctrl+Z, and you need job control to do `fg` and `bg`, but I believe that you can always do `&`.  (3) Are you sure you need the `-i`?  What happens if you don’t use it?

Comment: @G-Man 1) that's because I don't see the  point of spawning an unnecessary subshell 2)no, backgrounding is a job control method, try it yourself 3)check my answer ....the other answer is always better, the shell way is just for the sake of showing how this can be done using shell internals..

Comment: (1) OK, I know that `(…)` creates a subshell and `{…}` doesn’t.  My point is that `(cmd₁; cmd₂) &` and `{ cmd₁; cmd₂;} &` ***both*** create subshells.  That’s why I called `{…} &` “misleading” — it looks like it uses one fewer process, but it doesn’t.  (2) Well, I don’t have access to a system that I can `ssh` into right now, so I ran some `at` jobs.  That’s pretty much the same thing, right? — running `sh` (`dash`) with no tty.  And I was able to put a command into the background with `&`.  Anything else you want me to try?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) I’m sorry, but I have absolutely no idea what you’re saying here.  Are you saying that souravc’s answer is better than yours, and you posted yours just for didactic purposes?